# Jest throws ReferenceError when using Flow generic types

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, flowtype, babel-jest, flow-typed

I got a React application using Redux, Flow-typed and Jest. In order to create my reducers, I use a custom generic factory `createReducer<S> (initialState: S, actions: any): Reducer<S>`

So that to create some reducer I do:

```
const FooReducer = createReducer<FooState>(initialState, {
  'ACTION_ADD_USER': () => 'Foo',
})
```

I have the following test case:

```
// @flow

import { createReducer } from 'create-reducer'

type AppState = { name: string }

const initialState: AppState = { name: '' }

const NameReducer = createReducer<AppState>(initialState, {
  'NAME_CHANGE': (state, name) => ({ ...state, name })
})

it('should change the name', () => {
  const action = { type: 'NAME_CHANGE', name: 'bar' }

  expect(NameReducer({ name: 'foo' }, action)).toEqual({ name: 'bar' })
})
```

Jest is throwing the following error:

> ```
> FAIL temp.spec.jsx
>
>   ● Test suite failed to run
>
>     ReferenceError: AppState is not defined
>
>        7 | const initialState: AppState = { name: '' }
>        8 | 
>     >  9 | const NameReducer = createReducer<AppState>(initialState, {
>          |                                   ^
>       10 |   'NAME_CHANGE': (state, name) => ({ ...state, name })
>       11 | })
>       12 | 
>
>       at Object.AppState (temp.spec.jsx:9:35)
> ```

For some reason Jest is not able to find my type definition, even if it is declared right there. I have been searching thoroughly for a workaround but haven't had any luck so far. Hopefully someone have an idea what's wrong here?

APPENDIX:

**Environment**

> ```
> babel-core        6.26.0
> babel-jest        23.6.0
> babel-loader      6.4.1
> babel-preset-flow 6.23.0
> flow-bin          0.89.0
> flow-typed        2.2.0
> jest              23.6.0
> ```

**.babelrc** (updated):

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-es2015-destructuring"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-flow",
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "env": {
    "start": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react",
        "stage-0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/spec/javascripts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'c3': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/c3.js',
    '\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/spec/javascripts/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
    '\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$': '<rootDir>/spec/javascripts/__mocks__/fileMock.js'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'jsx',
    'js'
  ],
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/spec/javascripts/__mocks__/global-mocks.js'
  ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    'node_modules',
    'app/javascript/src'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': './node_modules/babel-jest'
  },
  testURL: 'http://localhost',
  testRegex: '.*.spec.jsx',
  verbose: true
}
```

**createReducer.js**

```
function createReducer<S> (initialState: S, handlers: any): Reducer<S> {
  return function reducer (state = initialState, action) {
    if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
      return handlers[action.type](state, action)
    } else {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really have an answer but what looks weird to me is that Jest should not care about types at all, right? The idea is that `babel-jest` removes the flow types (babel-preset-flow) before jest is executed. On the other hand this is not a syntax error. Maybe you can share your babel config or a repo to reproduce?

Comment: Thanks @Herku! I added the config and some other modules I now think are relevant. I certainly wasn't using this preset so the problem must be there.. I'm still trying to make it work but please feel free to put this as an answer!

Comment: Have you tried adding `babel-preset-flow` to the presets? It also has to be the first one to run, not sure in which order they need to be but you should be able to figure that out. How do you run your app?

Comment: I added `babel-preset-flow` on top of my presets but nothing changed... It runs with webpack but the thing is, only when running Jest it fails. Webpack compilies just fine and app works nicely.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Croolsby I did not but I realized that, without specifying the Type it works just fine, Flow is able to figure out the type from the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

[babel-preset-flow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-flow) is invoked as `flow` preset in `.babelrc` file. Here is the updated version:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "flow",
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "env": {
    "start": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Default and test environment need the same configuration (no env/test configuration is necessary here).

`transform-es2015-destructuring` plugin is already included in [babel-preset-es2015](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015).

Comment: Thanks Andrea! I'm afraid Jest still throws the error... in fact both `babel-preset-flow` and `flow` are equivalent https://babeljs.io/docs/en/presets#preset-shorthand

Comment: Would you be able to provide your jest configuration?

Comment: Sure! there it is